# cakephp 3 deeper associations

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to find the right way to handel the next tabel setup.

Products is my main table and contains an id.
UsersCarts has an field product_id and with belongsTo it also loads the products.

So far no problem. I also have an table ProductsNettoDeals where I store possible netto prices. This table has it's own id an an product_id for the hasOne relation when loading products in the productcontroller.

When I load the UsersChart it loads it belongsTo products, but I also want the association with the table ProductsNettoDeals, but this table is connected with products through the id (products.id = products_netto_deals.product_id). I cant find the right syntax or association for the querybuilder. What I have so far:

```
// src/Model/Table/UsersCartsTable.php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersCartsTable extends Table
{

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('Products');
    $this->belongsTo('ProductsNettoDeals');
}

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    return $validator
        ->notEmpty('user_id', 'A user id is required')
        ->notEmpty('product_id', 'A product id is required');
}

public function findCart(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query 
    ->where([
    'user_id' => $options['user_id'],
    //'active' => '1'
    ])
    ->contain(['Products','ProductsNettoDeals'])
    //->select(['product_id','created','products.name','products.price','products.delivery_time']);
    ;

    return $query;
}
}
```

In this setup I always have the problem that the matching of the id's are wrong. With the products it's good. The users_carts.product_id links with the products.id, but the products_netto_deals.product_id should link with product.id and not with the users_carts.id. I tryed foreign key and bind, but both are an part of an solution.

Beside this problem, when connecting the association ProductsNettoDeals I get an error when activating the commented active => '1'. This field indicates if an record is active and should be loaded. The same field exist in the products_netto_deals tabel to indicate if an netto price is active.

Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'active' in where clause is ambiguous

Can anyone point me in the right direction for the correct way of the association and the error warning. Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP uses joins for fetching associations, in order to speed ud the information retrieval process. This means that when having column names repeated across different table, you will need to prefix the column names in the query clause"

Instead of:

```
$query->where(['active' => true]);
```

Do:

```
$query->where(['UsersCarts.active' => true])
```